# Is there a way to handle associations by proxy in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have a Person and a Task table. A person can have many tasks, but sometimes, a person can have a major task that is a combination of other tasks.  So for that I insert multiple rows of tasks, grouped.  But I don't want to add any other tables like BigTask.

So is there a way to handle creating Tasks by proxy like

Person is related by Proxy(abstract) to Task.

Such that I can save and init a Proxy and that will give me an array of 0 or more Task objects.

Comment: Don't think that proxys as you thought are a good idea but what about a self join, where you have the task model, and a task itself can have other tasks?

Comment: I know you don't want to, but I think you'll need to create another table (e.g. TaskSet) and use a has_many :through association.

Answer (score 0):

Fleshing out the ideas expressed in the comments above, I believe something like this should work:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :big_task, class_name: "Task"
  has_many :sub_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "big_task_id"
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :big_tasks, class_name: "Task"
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :sub_tasks, through: tasks
end
```

Then, of course, you will need to define a "big_task_id" field on your Task model so that you can associate it with the "big task."

This should enable things like:

```
p = Person.find(id)
biggie = p.tasks.create(title: "Clean house")
biggie.tasks.create(title: "Vaccuum")
biggie.tasks.create(title: "Wash Windows")
p.tasks.count # 3
p.sub_tasks.count # 2
p.big_tasks.count # 1
```